# parsing package error

Tags: android, apk, parsing-error

I am new to Android development.  I built a app that accesses a webpage using webview.  It's minimum sdk version is 7, which is Android version 2.1.  It runs on my phone which is a droid x2 version 2.3.4.  However, when I sent it to my friend who has android 2.2, it says Problem Parsing Package on the install screen.  I have asked on the #android-dev IRC and they have no idea.  Please help.
Here is the Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.alan.ALICE"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >

    <activity
        android:name=".ALICE"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: post your entire AndroidManifest.xml

Answer (score 1):

This is usually a problem with the file itself, not the sdk version.  How are you signing and packaging the apk?  Try right clicking on your project name in Eclipse and going to Export.

Comment: That is what I am doing. I am signing with the wizard.